# How to select rows in column "A" based on values and take actio on corresponding cells in column "F"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am at a lost on how to accomplish this task, so any help will be appreciated. I have a spreadsheet with about 9000 rows (snippet shown below) and I am attempting to do the following:

1) Select cells in column G if the values in column A are the same and merge the selected cells. 
2) Select cells in column F if the values in column A are the same, find average of the selected cells and input results in merged cell from task 1 above.

I have attempted to accomplish this via the macros in Excel, however, I lack the programming/scripting skills to get the desired results.

```
1.   A    B     C     D     E     F     G
2. 21004    High   date1   date2   date3   51
3. 21004    High   date1   date2   date3   51
4. 21004    High   date1   date2   date3   51
5. 21004    High   date1   date2   date3   60
6. 21003    High   date1   date2   date3   21
7. 21003    High   date1   date2   date3   44
8. 21011    High   date1   date2   date3   55
9. 21011    High   date1   date2   date3   58
10. 21405    High   date1   date2   date3   91
11. 21405    High   date1   date2   date3   36
```

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub AverageFinG()
    Dim topA As Range, bottomA As Range, sliceF As Range, sliceG As Range
    Set topA = Cells(1, 1)
   Do Until IsEmpty(topA.Value)
        Set bottomA = topA
        Do While bottomA.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value = bottomA.Value
            Set bottomA = bottomA.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        Loop

        Set sliceF = Range(topA, bottomA).Offset(ColumnOffset:=5)
        Set sliceG = sliceF.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
        sliceG.Merge
        sliceG.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" + sliceF.Address + ")"

        Set topA = bottomA.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Loop
End Sub
```